# Rajya Dharma and its core values?

Tags: dharma

Does Hinduism formulate the rules and regulations for a King or a government?

What are the core values of Rajya Dharma?

Which scriptures mention those values?

Comment: although it is not a scripture in traditional sense, but as historically reverred text - you should still read **"chankya's arthashashtra"** and **"chankya's neetishashtra(ie, chankya niti)"** too

Answer (score 3):

The rules for a king and government are written in the Laws of Manu. Chapters VII and VIII. VII. 1. says:

> 1. I will declare the duties of kings, (and) show how a king should conduct himself, how he was created, and how (he can obtain) highest success.

And ends with VIII. 420.:

> 420. A king who thus brings to a conclusion. all the legal business enumerated above, and removes all sin, reaches the highest state (of bliss).

I won't put all the verses in the answer because together they are 646 verses. The Laws of Manu are available here -  http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/manu.htm